# Trading on historical data with TradingView Paper Trading

Tags: paper-trading

I'm studying quite a bit right now to initiate myself to the world of trading and since I haven't any experience, I don't want to risk real money testing my knowledge.

I've found TradingView has a good platform and also a free and unlimited demo account in which I can test my learning. The only blocking point I'm experiencing is even I can use historical data and watch it progress through time, I cannot place order on those prices and so I cannot test my strategies during the weekend when I have all the time to study. I know that could be done using pinescript, but an automatic trading strategy is something I'm not interested in right now.

Does anyone know if there's something I can do? I'm using the free account, so maybe the upgrade to a payment profile does the trick? Or maybe I can switch to some other platform and operate on that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you considered doing literal paper trading by recording your trades using a paper and pencil? This exercise only requires a source of market prices, which TradingView already provides.

Comment: How often do you plan to place trades? Several times per day? Several times per hour?

Comment: Several times per day.
I didn't consider to record trades by paper and pencil because it's not efficient, time consuming and moreover I have to write down all the statistics I could have done by a machine. I thought it was something easily doable since we have the possibility to play/pause on historical data.

Comment: Take a look at ThinkOrSwims's demo (TD Ameritrade).  I believe that you can go back in time and test intraday, going forward.